# Having only Https setup for the Domain using Route 53 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

We have a Domain set up from route 53.

currently, it is working both with HTTP://domainname and Https://domainname.

We want to have it restricted only to Https.
How can we achieve this in AWS?

Comment: This should be done on the backend. Are you using load balancer, cloud front or an instance to server your content?

Comment: We are using a Load Balancer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the application load balancer (ALB) is used, http to https redirection should be performed on ALB. The procedure is described in recent **AWS blog** post:

- [How can I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb)

It involves setting up HTTP listener which will redirect HTTP requests on port 80 to HTTPS listener on port 443.

To enable this, HTTPS listener must be setup with SSL certificate. The easiest to use would be to get **free SSL certificate** from AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) as shown in:

- [How can I associate an ACM SSL/TLS certificate with a Classic, Application, or Network Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/associate-acm-certificate-alb-nlb)

Comment: we have implemented it. Everything looks good but we also want people who will be typing http://prod.yp-uae.waveaxis.space/ directed to https://prod.yp-uae.waveaxis.space/ . PS: we have ALB which handles https and connects to ec2 on port 80

Comment: @sumanthshetty Hi. I does not work? Seems to me that it works fine.

Comment: Got it Marcin, I just had to redirect it in the rules